# Conditionally assigning to properties during non-destructive mutation of a record type

Tags: c#

I've been trying to utilize immutable `record` types for some of my DTO objects. I find that non-destructive mutation, while it looks pretty when you have a straightforward property assignment, is a bit more unwieldy when there's a lot of conditional logic. For example, assume this record:

```cs
public record MyDto
{
    int? Id { get; init; }
    // Some other irrelevant stuff
}
```

The logic for working for my DTOs is basically to invoke a `GET` endpoint to obtain the data for `MyDto`, modify that data locally, and send `MyDto` back up in a `PUT` request. In this example, I only want to assign to `Id` if an override of mine is not `null`. Sometimes, for other properties, the logic can be different. But ultimately the goal is the same: Assign a value to a particular property if some condition is met, otherwise leave it alone.

In the case of the `Id` property, I am doing the following:

```cs
public MyDto UpdateTheDto(MyDto dto, int? overrideId)
{
    return dto with
    {
        Id = overrideId ?? dto.Id
    }
}
```

The null coalescing logic above isn't terrible, but leaves me with two questions:

1. Is there a better syntax? For example, would it be better to make `Id` mutable (i.e. use `set` instead of `init`)?
2. Does this impact the performance of non-mutable destruction? What I recall from the official docs is that non-destructive mutation is smart enough to know its not cloning the whole record when you change one or two properties. However, in the scenario where `fallbackId` is null and it coalesces to `dto.Id`, is the compiler smart enough to see that this is a no-op and behaves exactly as it would if I had no assignment to `Id` to begin with?

I'm not sure if immutable records are the right tool for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: _"What I recall from the official docs is that non-destructive mutation is smart enough to know its not cloning the whole record when you change one or two properties"_ - can you please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe just use explicit constructors? It's hard to see how exactly this is being used.

Comment: @GuruStron I was referring to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation. It says: *"The result of a with expression is a shallow copy, which means that for a reference property, only the reference to an instance is copied. Both the original record and the copy end up with a reference to the same instance."* It's possible I have misunderstood it or that my explanation was odd.

Comment: @void.pointer it is not about the record itself but record properties. I.e. if you have `public object Something {get;init;}` (i.e. property storing a reference) after using the non-destructive copy with `with` (if the prop is not "updated") both new and old record instances will reference the same `object` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better syntax?

Personally I can't think of one (with keeping the design)

> For example, would it be better to make `Id` mutable

I would argue that in this case the `record` does not seem to be a right tool for the job since it was designed to easily design immutable data models and may result in some misuse.

> However, in the scenario where `fallbackId` is null and it coalesces to `dto.Id`, is the compiler smart enough to see that this is a no-op and behaves exactly as it would if I had no assignment to Id to begin with?

No and it you can check the decompilation [@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACATgUwMYHtkBNEFkBPAEQBdNYBvWASAEsA7UgfkQEk9LEBzVUgbkSM6AxAF9aAekmIAypgC2qRJlIALVMiHI0AG1QA3AIZNEAZ1IBXAGbXatBARLlEAVQAOOI6VQAVDWSYABREgYg45AA0QkysmAaayHQ4qBwAlLTUMDQ0IADs4S4A7iJqtDRZOTQciAC8Kgk6yal4zKwRmAB0HOVi/LQSMGJAA==). The code of the method is turned into something like the following:

```cs
public MyDto UpdateTheDto(MyDto dto, Nullable<int> overrideId)
{
    MyDto myDto = dto.<Clone>$();
    Nullable<int> num = overrideId;
    myDto.Id = (num.HasValue ? num : dto.Id);
    return myDto;
}
```

> I'm not sure if immutable records are the right tool for what I'm trying to do.

It seems that usual classes with mutable properties which would just check the incoming value would be a better option. But without seeing the whole codebase it is a bit hard to tell.